# Returning values from InputFormat via the Hadoop Configuration object

Tags: configuration, hadoop, split, jobs

Consider a running `Hadoop` job, in which a custom InputFormat needs to communicate ("return", similarly to a callback) a few simple values to the driver class (i.e., to the class that has launched the job), from within its overriden `getSplits()` method, using the new `mapreduce` API (as opposed to `mapred`).

These values should ideally be returned in-memory (as opposed to saving them to `HDFS` or to the `DistributedCache`).

If these values were only numbers, one could be tempted to use `Hadoop` counters. However, in numerous tests counters do not seem to be available at the `getSplits()` phase and anyway they are restricted to numbers.

An alternative could be to use the `Configuration` object of the job, which, as the source code reveals, should be the same object in memory for both the `getSplits()` and the driver class.

In such a scenario, if the `InputFormat` wants to "return" a (say) positive long value to the driver class, the code would look something like:

```
// In the custom InputFormat.
public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job) throws IOException
{
    ...
    long value = ... // A value >= 0
    job.getConfiguration().setLong("value", value);
    ...
}


// In the Hadoop driver class.
Job job = ... // Get the job to be launched
...
job.submit(); // Start running the job
... 
while (!job.isComplete())
{
    ...

    if (job.getConfiguration().getLong("value", -1))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        continue; // Wait for the value to be set by getSplits()
    }

    ...     
}
```

The above works in tests, but is it a "safe" way of communicating values?

Or is there a better approach for such in-memory "callbacks"?

**UPDATE**

The "in-memory callback" technique may not work in all `Hadoop` distributions, so, as mentioned above, a safer way is, instead of saving the values to be passed back in the `Configuration` object, create a custom object, serialize it (e.g., as JSON), saved it (in HDFS or in the distributed cache) and have it read in the driver class. I have also tested this approach and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the configuration is a perfectly suitable solution (admittedly for a problem I'm not sure I understand), but once the job has actually been submitted to the Job tracker, you will not be able to amend this value (client side or task side) and expect to see the change on the opposite side of the comms (setting configuration values in a map task for example will not be persisted to the other mappers, nor to the reducers, nor will be visible to the job tracker).

So to communicate information back from within getSplits back to your client polling loop (to see when the job has actually finished defining the input splits) is fine in your example.

What's your greater aim or use case for using this?

Comment: The main idea is to determine if the splitting phase has been finished and what kind of result has produced, so for instance the number of splits is saved in the Configuration object, along with some other values. None of these values needs to be propagated to the mappers, so if they are available in the driver class, irrespective of the job completion status (i.e., even after the job is completed, failed or successful), it is just fine. Based on my tests and what you say, the values should always be available in the driver class, if set in the getSplits() method. Will that be the case?

Comment: In trying to follow through the source, the JobContext passed to the getSplits looks like it's getting a cloned copy of the configuration (see the `JobContext.<init>(Configuration, JobID)` constructor) - so i wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work - but your tests are showing that it does work - in which case i think you have your answer

Comment: I have seen the source code, too, which is why I am puzzled, since it does work.